# Class number of cyclotomic extension

Tags: class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Show that the class number of Q$(\zeta_m)$ divides the class 
number of Q$(\zeta_n)$ if $m$ divides $n$.

I've found this statement in some notes on class field theory, but I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: What is the definition of the class number?

Comment: The order of the ideal class group of the ring of integers.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Look at $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ having two kind of ideals : the principal ideals $\alpha R, \alpha \in R$ and non-principal ideals $\beta R + \beta (1+\sqrt{-5}), \beta \in \frac{1}{2}R+ \frac{1-\sqrt{-5}}{2} R$. Thus the class number is $2$.

Comment: Ok so, roughly,  it's the number of "types" of ideals.

Comment: The degree of the first cyclotomic extension divides that of the second  (you probably know ), as they are the values of the euler phi function at n and m, I noticed. ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first prove that the maximal abelian subextension of the Hilbert class field of a full cyclotomic field is the cyclotomic field itself. This then implies the existence of an unramified abelian extension of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_n)$ with degree $h({\mathbb Q}(\zeta_m))$.